# Fix configuration problems with MacPorts MySQL

Tags: mysql, macports

I have mysql/mysqli installed on my local machine via MacPorts and can access mysql/mysqli commands from the command line ONLY when using locahost.

If I try running:

mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p

I get the following error:

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

When running:

mysql -u root -h localhost -p

Everything is fine.

The reason this bothers me is that I am trying to use mysqli_connect in a PHP script running on localhost.  When I enter the host as localhost, it gives me this error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in ... on line 2
bool(false) Failed to connect to MySQL: No such file or directory

And when I enter the host as 127.0.0.1, I get a different error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /Users/raph/coding/webroot/rugapp/qbo-palmer/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/test.php on line 2
bool(false) Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection refused

It seems as though I have some configuration problems.  What is the best way to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

The connection to localhost uses a unix socket. It seems the correct socket path is built into the mysql binary you use, which explains why it works on the command line. For the unix socket connection to work from PHP, you need to specify MacPorts MySQL's non-standard socket path as you would normally specify a port number.

For the failure to connect using 127.0.0.1 (which forces IPv4 and avoids the unix socket), see [mysql running but cannot connect to 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26538112/2127896).